# error in quick box popup in html not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a store website in which while clicking the eye icon or expand icon in some images, the quick box shows up with some description.

```
<div class="ImageWrapper">
    <div class="product-button">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="promise-solitaire-ring-mount" class="quick-view-text">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-eye"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="products\promise-solitaire-ring-mount.html">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-link"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="add-to-wishlist">
            <div class="show">
                <div class="default-wishbutton-promise-solitaire-ring-mount loading">
                    <a class="add-in-wishlist-js btn" href="promise-solitaire-ring-mount">
                        <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
                        <span class="tooltip-label">
                            Add to wishlist
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </div>
               <div class="loadding-wishbutton-promise-solitaire-ring-mount loading btn" style="display: none; pointer-events: none">
                   <a class="add_to_wishlist" href="promise-solitaire-ring-mount">
                       <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>
                   </a>
               </div>
               <div class="added-wishbutton-promise-solitaire-ring-mount loading" style="display: none;">
                   <a class="added-wishlist btn add_to_wishlist" href="pages\wishlist.html">
                       <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                       <span class="tooltip-label">
                           View Wishlist
                       </span>
                   </a>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="product-detail">
    <div class="product_left">
        <a href="collections\new-arrivals\products\promise-solitaire-ring-mount.html" class="grid-link__title">
            Let Promise Solitaire Ring Mount
        </a>
        <div class="grid-link__meta">
            <div class="product_price">
                <div class="grid-link__org_price">
                    <span class="money">$590.00</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="shopify-product-reviews-badge" data-id="10109315278"></span>
        </div>
```

The complete files are [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cvoPz3L83mlK2Q78l2nlRqA-_r2Bmd-h).

When I click the icon, the popup is not shown, instead, a light-black shade is shown:

### [image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: Check your console for any `errors` if present.

Comment: Could be a CSS issue when the overlay box is displayed. You have two vertical scrollbars which would be an indicator that there's a problem with scaling and positioning of elements. Not related to the problem but use forward slashes ("/") in the `href` of an anchor.

Comment: Just had a look at your code (which is quite messed up, i.e. there are JS and CSS files in the "images" folder ...), it might be a problem that the currently selected product can't be loaded from the backend. Set a breakpoint in "shope3ea.js", line 782 and see if any product records are returned.

Comment: @SaschaM78 i checked the problem is a js file is not being loaded, but i am not able to find in which line the js code is defined, i tried searching the line which i got from my browser but nothing like that exist in my project

Comment: Did you check if shope3ea.js is included? Would you be able to temporarily host the application somewhere were it is publicly available? Otherwise it will be impossible to assist.

Comment: After formatting your code, I'm noticing that there are two unclosed `div` at the end and an extra closing `div` in the middle of your code (indentation is handy to detect these kinds of errors). Check if your issue is not related to this.